# Does representation irreducibility ensure non-zero determinant?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, determinant

If a set of matrix representation $\{M(g)\}$ for a group $G$ is irreducible, what can we say about their determinant for every $g\in G$? Are they all of non-zero determinant?

Thank you very much!

Cheers,
Collin

---

P.S.: I'm a physics graduate student. So please use as little math terminology as possible, I would really appreciate that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inverse of $M(g)$ is $M(g^{-1})$.

And of course, invertible matrices have non-zero determinant.

Note that this is true for all representations, not just irreducible ones.

Comment: Oh, Yes!  You're so right sir.  I can't believe this. I just read this sentence yesterday.  Thank you!  ^. ^ @DanielMroz